# RouteController failed to create a route on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster on GKE whose node pool I create when I want to use the cluster, and delete when I'm done with it.

It's a two node cluster with the master in `europe-west2-a` and with and whose node zones are `europe-west2-a` and `europe-west2-b`.

The most recent creation resulted in the node in zone B failing with `NetworkUnavailable` because `RouteController failed to create a route`. The reason was because `Could not create route xxx 10.244.1.0/24 for node xxx after 342.263706ms: instance not found`.

Why would this be happening all of a sudden, and what can I do to fix it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which version of GKE you are using so just for clarification:

> Changes in [access scopes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/access-scopes#changes)
>   Beginning with Kubernetes version 1.10, gcloud and GCP Console no longer grants the compute-rw access scope on new clusters and new node pools by default. Furthermore, if --scopes is specified in gcloud container create, gcloud no longer silently adds compute-rw or storage-ro.

In any case you can still revert to legacy access scopes but this is not recommended approach.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

With gke 1.13.6-gke.13, some of the default scopes were changed, including the `compute-rw` scope being removed. I *think* that due to the age of the cluster, this scope was necessary for a route to be correctly created between nodes in a node pool.

In the end, my gcloud creation command had these scopes:

`--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting,storage-rw,monitoring,trace,compute-rw`

Comment: Hi, I have just created 1.13.6-gke.13 cluster with nodes in different zones.
I am not sure you are right with those statements: As per documentation:
__Route Controller__: `For setting up routes in the underlying cloud infrastructure`. Please provide full command you have performed to create your cluster, and more details how we can recreate this issue.

Comment: The command I was using was:

`gcloud container node-pools create preemptible-pool  --cluster staging --zone europe-west2-a --num-nodes 1 --machine-type "n1-standard-4" --preemptible --image-type=COS_CONTAINERD --scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting,storage-rw,monitoring,trace"`

Comment: So its working at the moment or do we have still to follow your issue?

Comment: It's all sorted now :) Thank you!