# How to fix NetworkUnavailable:True error in kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

Node:

`Status NetworkUnavailable: True`

Message error:

> RouteController failed to create a route

[image]
Try delete the node and create new node. After create new node status returned to normal.

How to troubleshoot or check problem

Comment: please add more details : full error  ( screenshot ) k8s version.  network plugin are you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RouteController failed to create a route on GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722303/routecontroller-failed-to-create-a-route-on-gke)

Comment: @eranmeiri  How to check network plugin , k8s version 1.13.7-gke.8

Comment: @KamolHasan Will try to check. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get more info from your problem you can retrieve logs from StackDriver--> Logging --> Loggs viewer, user "Advanced Filter" and there search by "Status NetworkUnavailable: True Message error" or "RouteController failed to create a route"

Comment: Use advanced logs query >> "Status NetworkUnavailable: True Message error" or "RouteController failed to create a route" ? It can't find.

Comment: Are you using Logs viewer-->Convert to advanced filter?

Comment: Yes,I use Convert to advanced filter.

Comment: Check if your quota of routes are not exceeded

Comment: Quota are not exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when a component in K8s decides your network is unavailable.  For example,

- in calico, there is code which toggles this "true" or "false"
- in antrea, another CNI provider, the same thing can occur

USUALLY this means that your CNI provider is "not ready".

## So why might a CNI provider fail to set NetworkUnavailable: false ?

- Your Node that the CNI runs on is missing a some network tech that the CNI depends on (i.e. maybe OVS (antreA) or BGP (calico) doesnt work on your version of linux, or you havent installed these drivers in your windows machine).
- Maybe your CNI provider cannot access the kubernetes API Server to update the node's conditions metadata.  This might be an RBAC related error (you would see this in the CNI providers logs)... https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/7996 .

In any case you can try to manually run a pod to see if "The CNI is up, but the node just has a false condition".  In this case either:

- the container will fail to "create" because containerd wasn't able to get an IP from the CNI or
- the container will succeed in which case, you have a metadata bug in your cluster - i.e. some component isn't updating the node condition accurately.

There is work to be done in Kubernetes itself to improve the documentation around this "node condition" and make it easier to interpret in the future (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#condition).